# Resizing Nested NSViews

Tags: cocoa, nsview, core-plot, nsviewcontroller

In order to categorize a wide variety of unique views, I have an elaborate setup: main categories are selected via a toolbar, and then specific panes are selected in a category's NSScrollView. This looks like: window -> NSViewController controlling five views -> sub-NSViewController for each view controlling X views -> each view contains a core-plot graph. In short, nested NSViewControllers with a core-plot CPLayerHostingView at the end of nearly every path.

Before I even get to my question, feel free to point out that this is a poor implementation. In terms of user-friendliness, I think it makes sense, but the sheer number of nested objects makes me wonder if there's a better way.

Now then, assuming I've designed it the best possible way, the question itself: suppose I have selected a category and then a sub-item within, and am looking at a rendered graph. I desire the graph to resize appropriately if the window is resized. In Interface Builder I have done everything necessary to make this happen: everything from the CPLayerHostingView to the NSView in the main window have been set to autosize in all directions. Despite this, if I resize at runtime, the graph stays still and does not resize or move. In a design with zero or one NSView tiers this would be much simpler to debug, but I'm out of ideas in this scenario.

What tricks, programmatic or IB-based, can I use to make sure an NSView resizes according to a window resize many, many levels up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only do you need to set the springs and struts, but you also need to make sure "Autoresizes Subviews" is checked.